# Powershell IIS plugin - cmdlets not working

Tags: iis, powershell

I'm pretty much a novice at Powershell so bear with my noobness. I'm specifically trying to run the "Get-WebBinding" cmdlet (which I have successfully run on some of my other servers)

Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard:

`Get-PsProvider`

Shows the WebAdministration module is not loaded

`Import-Module WebAdministration`

An error occurs. "Cannot be loaded because the execution of scripts is disabled....."

`Get-ExecutionPolicy`

Output is "restricted"

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

Confirmed with a Yes.

`Import-Module WebAdministration`

An error occurs. "...skipped because it's already present"

`Get-PsProvider`

Shows that WebAdministration is now installed

`Get-WebBinding` (the cmdlet I really want to run)

Another error. "not found"

Any ideas why this cmdlet won't run?

Comment: Have you tried `Add-PSSnapin WebAdministration` instead? [The docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790599.aspx) suggest the `Import-Module` on its own may not be sufficient.

Comment: What do you get for the output of "Get-Command Get-Web*"

Comment: Add-PSSnapin fails. It says the WebAdministration' snap-in isn't installed. (yet it seems to be installed given get-PSProvider)

Comment: Get-Command says there are no matching commands to "get-web*"

Comment: Does the problem still exist? Sounds to me as if it wasn't loaded properly due to the restrictive execution policy. Opening a new PS instance should probably fix the issue since the changed execution policy won't affect the loading of modules any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you managed to sort it but I do a bunch of stuff in IIS and need to run the following to enable it all:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll") | Out-Null
```